# Using a Textarea to create the contents of an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to make a program that takes the `value` of a textarea and uses that to make an array.

Typically an array would be made like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
</script
```

But I want to make it in a way like this:

```
<textarea id="textarea">1,2,3,4,5</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = '['+document.getElementById('textarea').value+']';
</script
```

Is there any way to do this with either jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: [`var data = document.getElementById('textarea').value.split(',')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Are only values of `textarea` digit characters separated by comma characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var myArray = document.getElementById('textarea').value.split(',') 
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
myArray[i] = +myArray[i];
} 
console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">1,2,3,4,5</textarea>
```

Comment: @FinleySherwood I just updated my answer to make sure you get an array that has numbers as its elements and not strings

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="textarea">1,2,3,4,5</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = document.getElementById("textarea").value.split(",");
    console.log(array);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that can help

```
    <textarea id="textarea">1,2,3,4,5</textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // get textarea value
        var data = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
        // split value into an array
        var dataArray = data.split(',');

        // display data array in console 
        for (var i = 0 ; i < dataArray.length; i++){
     console.log( dataArray[i]);
        }
    </script>
```